# Broadcast receiver not working?

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-broadcast

I m using a broadcast receiver with multiple intent filters. My requirement is to access the click of notification and make a job with that click in background(if app minimised) or foreground. The first two jobs are finishing, but the third one not executing. Where i m wrong ?
Here is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
            int choice; EditText et;
            @override
              onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
           et= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.choice);
       choice=Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
               //some_stuff
        if (choice==1)
       registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("ACT_ONE");
       else if (choice==2){
       registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("ACT_TWO");
       registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("ACT_THREE");
        }
        else if (choice==3) {

             NotificationCompat.Builder nb=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    nb.setContentTitle("Do Job_Four");
                    nb.setContentText("Click here to do job four");
                    nb.setAutoCancel(true);
                    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                    nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                    Intent in=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                    IntentFilter lf=new IntentFilter("ACT_FOUR");
                    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,(int)System.currentTimeMillis(),in,0);
                    nb.setContentIntent(pi);
                    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    registerReceiver(br,lf);
                    nm.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),nb.build());
            }
         }
            private void m_one(){
                //job_one_code

            }
            private void m_two(){
                //job_two_code
            }
          private void m_three(){
            //job_three_code
        }
            BroadcastReceiver br=new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @override
            onReceive(Context c, Intent i){
            if(i.getAction().equals("ACT_ONE")
                 m_one();
            else if(i.getAction().equals("ACT_TWO")
                 m_two();
            else if(i.getAction().equals("ACT_THREE")
                 m_two();
            else if(i.getAction().equals("ACT_FOUR")
                m_three();
            }
            };
            @override
            public void onDestroy(){
            unregisterReceiver(br);
            super.onDestroy();
            }
            }
```

Here is manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
       <action android:name="ACT_ONE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my pseudo code:-- Please register onPause() and unregister 
on onResume() method it will work.


public class AndroidBroadcast extends Activity {

                        private BroadcastReceiver the_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

                                @Override
                                public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

                                }
                        };
                        // Set When broadcast event will fire.
                        private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);

                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                             setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("ax.chayan.mybroadcast");
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onResume() {

                            // Register reciever if activity is in front
                            this.registerReceiver(the_receiver, filter);
                            super.onResume();
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPause() {

                             // Unregister reciever if activity is not in front
                             this.unregisterReceiver(the_receiver);
                             super.onPause();
                        }

                }
```

Comment: I just added " intent.setAction("some_Action")" It is hleped me thank you, but is there any difference b/w intent= new Intent("some_action") and setAction methods ?